# How to increase deployment gate timeout

Tags: azure, azure-devops, timeout

I have a release on Azure DevOps and I would like to know how I can increase the deployment gate timeout to 5 days. How do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to be followed to increase the deployment gate time out value:

- Select the release pipeline on which you want to change the gateway time-out value.
- Click on pre-deployment conditions>Select Gates >click on Evaluation Options drop-down & increase the time out value to 5 days.

To test this in our local environment, we have created a new release pipeline with an empty job & querying work items as evaluation conditions & in the evaluation options, we have changed the value of deployment gate evaluation time out to 5 days as shown in the below gif.

[image]

You can refer to [this](https://rabiawilliams.com/azure/deployment-gates/) blog post for more information about deployment gates.